# RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "User" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection? Typeorm

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am having a fun issue trying to get TypeOrm to work in my nestjs project.

I have the below code to configure my project, yes everything loads, and yes I am able to connect to my database.

```
import { CacheModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AuthenticationController } from './controllers/authentication.controller';
import { AuthenticationService } from './services/authentication.service';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { BaseEntity } from './entities/base.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 5432,
        username: 'postgres',
        password: process.env.POSTGRE_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DATABASE,
        migrationsTableName: 'migration_table',
        entities: [User, BaseEntity],
        migrations: [__dirname + '/migrations/**/*.ts'],
        subscribers: [__dirname + '/subscribers/**/*.ts'],
        cli: {
          entitiesDir: '/entitys',
          migrationsDir: '/migrations',
          subscribersDir: '/subscribers',
        },
        synchronize: true,
        autoLoadEntities: true,
    }),
    CacheModule.register(),
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'myprivatekey',
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '1d' },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthenticationController],
  providers: [AuthenticationService],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private connection: Connection) {}
}
```

and here are the entities:

```
import {
  Column,
  BeforeUpdate,
  BeforeInsert,
} from 'typeorm';

export class BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  created_at: Date;

  @Column({
    default: new Date(),
  })
  updated_at: Date;

  @BeforeUpdate()
  updateUpdatedAt() {
    this.updated_at = new Date();
  }

  @BeforeInsert()
  updateCreatedAt() {
    this.created_at = new Date();
  }
}
```

```
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Generated,
} from 'typeorm';

import { BaseEntity } from './base.entity';

@Entity('users')
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @Generated('uuid')
  uuid: string;

  @Column()
  first_name: string;

  @Column()
  last_name: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column({
    default: false,
  })
  confirmed: boolean;

  @Column({
    default: null,
  })
  seller_id: string;

  @Column({
    default: null,
  })
  auth_token: string;

  @Column({
    default: false,
  })
  is_admin: boolean;
}
```

I originally tried doing a glob pattern match, to no avail, so now I am directly importing in my Entities until I can get something to run. Also note, that all my modules load prior to the error above and the error is from using the @InjectRepository() decorator within either the AuthenticationController or AdminController. Everywhere I have looked has said its because my entities are not being loaded, which I am not sure how that is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

In my case I had an error on Production mode, to fix it I added the path of the compiled JS files in the `build` folder.

```js
const conn: MongoConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'mongodb',
  url: DB_URL,
  synchronize: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  logging: true,
  entities: ['src/entity/*.ts', './build/src/entity/*.js'], // <- Here!
  migrations: ['src/migration/**/*.ts'],
  subscribers: ['src/subscriber/**/*.ts'],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: 'src/entity',
    migrationsDir: 'src/migration',
    subscribersDir: 'src/subscriber',
  },
  extra: {
    authSource: DB_AUTH_SOURCE,
  },
};
```

The short version could be: `entities: ['**/src/entity/*{.ts,.js}'],`

Answer (score 17):

Try giving a name to your entity with the @Entity decorator:

```
import { Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column } from "typeorm";
@Entity("category") // <-- Right here
```

Comment: Yes .. that works .

Answer (score 8):

seems like it is, as you said, because the entities are not loaded.

my guess is :
the config file you have added tries to find the files at :

```
  migrations: [__dirname + '/migrations/**/*.ts'],
  subscribers: [__dirname + '/subscribers/**/*.ts'],
```

are those entity files in the same dir as the module is? could help to print the output of those paths just to make sure it is correct.

also note that typescript compiles to javascript, so you might run into the same problem if you run the code from /dist, because it will be able to see only the ".js" compiled files, so i'd suggest to use

```
  migrations: [__dirname + '/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
  subscribers: [__dirname + '/subscribers/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
```

if its nothing of the above 2 options, please provide the full routes of the entities and modules in play.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue, glob paths don't work in case of `monorepo`.

> Note, however, that **glob paths are not supported by webpack**, so if you are building your application within a **monorepo**, you won't be able to use them. To address this issue, an alternative solution is provided. To automatically load entities, set the autoLoadEntities property of the configuration object (passed into the forRoot() method).

> Note that entities that aren't registered through the forFeature() method, but are only referenced from the entity (via a relationship), won't be included by way of the autoLoadEntities setting.

-- [NestJS Docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#auto-load-entities)

Also, I was using `ormconfig.ts`, which also presents one more difficulty -

> Note that the ormconfig.json file is loaded by the typeorm library. Thus, any of the extra properties described above (which are supported internally by way of the forRoot() method - for example, autoLoadEntities and retryDelay) won't be applied. Luckily, TypeORM provides the getConnectionOptions function that reads connection options from the ormconfig file or environment variables. With this, you can still use the configuration file and set Nest-specific options.

-- [NestJS Docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database)

#### Final Solution

1. root/main module -

```
import { getConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';
...
@Module({
  imports: [
   TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
    useFactory: async () =>
      Object.assign(await 
       getConnectionOptions(), {
        autoLoadEntities: true,
      }),
    })
   ],
 ...
})
```

2. app/child module -

```
...
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([<entities go here>])],
  ...
})
...
```

Comment: Thanks this did the trick for me. I am also using a monorepo.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I solved it by declaring the entity in the connection file.

The TypeORM documentation explains this change.

## Creating a connection to the database

Now, when our entity is created, let's create an index.ts (or app.ts whatever you call it) file and set up our connection there:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
import { Photo } from "./entity/Photo";

createConnection({
    type: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    username: "root",
    password: "admin",
    database: "test",
    entities: [
        Photo
    ],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false
}).then(connection => {
    // here you can start to work with your entities
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: this approach is perfect when you have entities outside of your root folder, like monorepos or some folder/files with shared logic to use across multiples projects.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put the @ sign in front of your entity decorator (3 of my entities didn't and the error message was related to the relations because it didn't find my entites)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I added the following properties in my ormconfig:

```js
"cli":{
    "migrationsDir":"./src/database/migrations",
    "entitiesDir": ".src/modules/cars/entities"
  },
  "entities": [
    "./src/modules/cars/entities/**/*{.ts,.js}" 
]
```

Works fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

I had everything correct except the filename.

It should be like
**`entityname.entity.ts`**

But it was like
**`entityname.ts`**

Answer (score 0):

When reading the source code I realized that the strings are still there (inside the JS bundle), so it is calling something that is just not there as all files are inside of it, I tried importing the models directly within the app.module and not passing strings or patterns to the entities array, but the imported entity classes instead, that worked like a charm.

Given, this may not be the  cleanest approach, because you have to write the paths in the imports to different modules and import them one by one. It would be great to see what others have to say on how to tackle and improve on this so that we can achieve a cleaner solution.

This works today as of Nov/2021.

Answer (score 0):

Also check your connection, if entities are `entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js']`, make sure your file name is `{name}.entity.ts`

Answer (score 0):

in base entity you havent provided decorator @Entity()

```
@Entity()
export class BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  created_at: Date;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I had the repository inside the list of:

```
TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ 
    TblX,
    RepositoryX
]),
```

Removing RepositoryX from here fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There is one additional case not covered by these answers. I made a copy of a resolver file and put it on the same level as my `tsconfig.json` file. I got this same error because, during the build and run, the top-level resolver file was processed. This meant that any entity it tried to load could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in typeorm config.

```
const ORMConfig: ConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  synchronize: true,
  url,
  logging: ['error'],
  entities: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'entities/*{.ts,.js}'),
    path.join(__dirname, './dist/db/entities/*.ts,.js'),
  ],
  migrations: [path.join(__dirname, 'migrations/*{.ts,.js}')],
  subscribers: [path.join(__dirname, 'subscribers/*{.ts,.js}')],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: 'src/db/entities',
    migrationsDir: 'src/db/migrations',
    subscribersDir: 'src/db/subscribers',
  },
  migrationsTableName: 'migration',
  // add this 
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code `entities: [User, BaseEntity]` with `autoLoadEntities: true`

Answer (score -2):

If all of the answers above do not work, you could simply just clear and rebuild the `dist` directory by running the following command

```
npm run build
```

Then, restart your application

```
npm run start:dev
```

Comment: This will not solve anything